# Should I re-phrase my question, or make comments to answers?

Tags: discussion

When I wrote my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280277/adding-counts-of-a-factor-to-a-dataframe), I assumed that the order of the data would be preserved, but the answer I got resulted in the order changing . I've put some comments to the answer but I wondered if I should perhaps rephrase the question instead to make it clear that I want the order of the data to be preserved ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would add what you write in that comment in the question. As it is now, that comment is probably only read from who reads that answer, but it is relevant to everybody who could answer you.

Comment: I would too, but in this specific case, I wonder if that would change the question. If it would change it very much (invalidating the existing answer), a *new* question might be more appropriate?

Comment: @Arjan It's not a new question, it's a clarification of the existing one. A new question is not justified here, in my opinion.

Comment: @Arjan IMO, it makes explicit something the OP assumed, and it could be seen as additional requirement that doesn't radically change the question.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase that, just for future reference: *if* adding the details would invalidate existing answers (which, without the edit were okay), then I'd consider asking a new question instead.

Comment: Thanks - I've added a comment to the question.